# Understanding the cohomology ring of the Grassmannian

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

Some background first: I'm trying to understand the solution of some enumerative geometry problems, such as proving that a smooth cubic contains $27$ lines. I know that this becomes easier once one understands the cohomology of the Grassmannian.

I know that the Grassmannian can be given a CW-complex structure, but I don't understand how to compute the actual cohomology ring. I think that is the subject of Schubert calculus, and names like Pieri's or Giambelli's formulas often pop up. But I have also read elsewhere, such as in Hatcher's book *Vector Bundles and K-Theory*, that one can use Chern classes to describe the cohomology ring.

My question is, how are the two approaches related, and, most importantly, what is a comprehensive textbook on the subject?

Comment: Milnor does not have a book called *Vector Bundles and K-Theory*. There is a book in progress by Hatcher of that name.

Comment: Thank you. I have been reading Milnor's *Characteristic classes* and got the two mixed up.

Comment: Eisenbud and Harris [_3264 and All That: A Second Course in Algebraic Geometry_](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139062046).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two texts I have most often been referred to for studying the cohomology of the Grassmannian are *Young Tableaux* by Fulton and *Symmetric Functions, Schubert Polynomials, and Degeneracy Loci* by Manivel. From my perspective, Manivel takes a fairly combinatorial perspective while Part III of Fulton gives an excellent treatment of this question from a more geometric perspective.